# Webix. How to get attr value defined in template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webix

I did defined button template in Webix Datatable as following:

```
    grid = new webix.ui({
                container: "permissions",
                view: "datatable",
                columns: [
                    { id: "Id", adjust: "data", header: "&nbsp;", template: "<button value='#Id#' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs edit'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></button> <button value=#Id# class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></button>" }
                    ...Other columns here
 }
                ],
                pager: {
                    container: "paging_here",
                    size: 10,
                    group: 5
                },
                autoheight: true,
                minHeight: 50,
                autowidth: true,
                on: {
                    onBeforeLoad: function () {
                        this.showOverlay("Загрузка данных...");
                    },
                    onAfterLoad: function () {
                        this.hideOverlay();
                    }
                },
                url: "" + _args[0] + ""
            });
```

Unfortunately I do not have any idea how to get value of attribute defined in button template. I try something like that but it's not working:

```
grid.on_click.edit = function (e, id, trg, value) {
                //Core.init(["../Permissions/Edit/?id=" + e.Id]);
                //Core.loadModal();
                alert($(this).attr("value"));
                return false;
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer.
That's way.

```
grid.on_click.edit = function (e, id, trg, value) {
    alert(grid.getItem(id).Id); //Where Id is value binded in column
    return false;
};
```